# When using the blade structure in Laravel 9, I get the error "Undefined variable $__env"

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-9

There is no problem when I get php's own tags instead of '@' tags. Can anyone make sense of this?

```php-template
<?php function buildCategory($parent, $category){ ?>
@isset($category['parent_cats'][$parent])
    <ul>
        @foreach ($category['parent_cats'][$parent] as $cat_id)
            @foreach ($category['userPagePerms'] as $userPagePerm)
                @if (!isset($category['parent_cats'][$cat_id]))
                    <li data-jstree='{"selected":{{ ($userPagePerm->backend_page_permission_id == $cat_id) ? 'true' : 'false' }},"opened":true}'>
                        <a href='{{$category['categories'][$cat_id]->id }}'> {{ $category['categories'][$cat_id]->name}}</a>
                    </li>
                @endif
                @if (isset($category['parent_cats'][$cat_id]))
                    <li data-jstree='{"selected":{{ ($userPagePerm->backend_page_permission_id == $cat_id) ? 'true' : 'false' }},"opened":true}'>
                        <a href='{{ $category['categories'][$cat_id]->id }}'>{{$category['categories'][$cat_id]->name }}</a>
                            <?php buildCategory($cat_id, $category); ?>
                    </li>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endisset
<?php } buildCategory(0, $category); ?>
```

It worked when using PHP's own tags. I would expect it to work with the '@' tag.

The code snippet I was able to run. Only the foreach part is the problem.

```php
<?php foreach ($category['parent_cats'][$parent] as $cat_id) {
    <?php foreach ($category['userPagePerms'] as $userPagePerm) { ?>
```

Error ss : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rOSP.png)

Comment: There is no `$__env` in your code at all. Please [edit] your question to include the full error and stack trace

Comment: @Phil I think that's the problem. I'm getting the same error as OP and stack trace does not show a `$__env` at all.  This would seem to be the laravel framework calling it somewhere down the line, but it's not obvious from the stack where and why it's failing.